# Problem - ST_AsGeoJSON return text with accolade

Tags: javascript, geojson, geometry

I am saving a result of  ST_AsGeoJSON(..) into csv file. But the results I got can't be interrupted as an object later on. How can I polish and delete the accolades that I don't need.

"{**""**type***""**:**""**MultiPolygon**""**,**""**coordinates**""*:[[[[-74.0758273156424,40.5922324042084],[-74.0761549604646,40.5921150798826],[-74.076200629116,40.5921869978165],[-74.0760676410383,40.5922346191496],[-74.0758729840191,40.5923043204707],[-74.0758273156424,40.5922324042084]]]]}"

Answer (score 1):

Copy and Paste the *ST_AsGeoJSON* result inside Notepad++.
Then go to `Search > Replace`.

Here, you can do all kind of polishes you want, like below:

In `Find what` type: **`[\{ \} \[ \]]`**

Let the `Replace with` field be empty.

Check `Regular expression` then you ca press `Replace All` to achieve your results:

[image]

Or, maybe you need something like this:

[image]

You can use the [Using RegEx with Notepad++](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/?title=Regular_Expressions) for more ideas when using regular expressions.

---

**EDIT**

Now, if you search for an *automatic cleaning* of your ST_AsGeoJSON(..), I'll give you below a starting point for such function building:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.polish(original_string character varying)
    RETURNS character varying AS $$
DECLARE
    start_pos integer;
    v_string  varchar = '';
BEGIN
    -- we'll obtain only an empty string if we don't
    -- remove the " (double quotes) character
    v_string := replace(original_string, '"', '');
    -- now we can perform any kind of operations
    start_pos := position('[[[[' in v_string);
    v_string := substring(v_string from start_pos);
    v_string := replace(v_string, '[[[[', '[');
    v_string := replace(v_string, ']]]]', ']');
     RETURN v_string;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

select polish('"{""*type"":""MultiPolygon"",""coordinates""*:[[[[-74.0758273156424,40.5922324042084],[-74.0761549604646,40.5921150798826],[-74.076200629116,40.5921869978165],[-74.0760676410383,40.5922346191496],[-74.0758729840191,40.5923043204707],[-74.0758273156424,40.5922324042084]]]]}"');
```

And the result is a very clean line:

[image]

You can modify this function, according your wishes (see [PL/pgSQL - SQL Procedural Language](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql.html))

Comment: This is non-automatic way to solve the prob.

Comment: The "automatic way" envolves some programming. Any language haves search-and-replace commands.

Comment: @user3001937 I've updated my answer with an automatic way to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

[ST_AsText()](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_AsText.html) gives you a format much more easy to work

```
MULTIPOLYGON(((115.821929931641 10.7119426727295,115.820266723633
10.7122192382813,115.814422607422 10.7244415283203,115.822769165039
10.7315254211426,115.834014892578 10.73069190979,115.840812683105
10.7211084365845,115.827629089355 10.7170810699463,115.821929931641 10.7119426727295)),
((114.372207641602 9.69972038269043,114.369430541992 9.70138740539551,114.368316650391
9.70499801635742,114.370246887207 9.7077751159668,114.373596191406
9.70833206176758,114.37776184082 9.70610809326172,114.377197265625
9.7027759552002,114.372207641602 9.69972038269043)))
```

Just remove the "MULTIPOLYGON" word and all ")" and "(".